# Custom taxonomy on permalink

Tags: custom-taxonomy, permalinks, url-rewriting, taxonomy, rewrite-rules

I have a long time problem and look forward for your help. 
I have a custom taxonomy of "city" (it is no hierarchical like tags).
I just would like my URLs to look like this:

```
/%city%/%category%/%postname%/
```

So this is what I like to accomplish.

- `http://example.com/city/moscow` - Display all posts in taxonomy city-Moscow.
- `http://example.com/category/shopping` - Display all posts in this category and all cities.
- `http://example.com/category/shopping/supermarket` - Display all posts in this category and all cities.
- `http://example.com/moscow/shopping/` -Display all posts in this category in Moscow.
- `http://example.com/moscow/shopping/supermarket/` - Display all posts in this -child-category in Moscow.
- `http://example.com/moscow/shopping/supermarket/postname` - Display the post.

**I’ve made the following**:

1. I’ve created a custom  taxonomy - city  at first.
2. I’ve added the code in function.php

```
function add_custom_taxonomies_city() {
    register_taxonomy('city', 'post', array(
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => _x( 'City', 'taxonomy general name' ),
            'search_items' =>  __( 'Search cities' ),
            'all_items' => __( 'All cities' ),
            'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Categories' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Categories:' ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit city' ), 
            'update_item' => __( 'Update city' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add city' ),
            'new_item_name' => __( 'New city' ),
            'menu_name' => __( 'cities' ),
            );    

        ),
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'city',
        'with_front' => false,
        'hierarchical' => false
        ),
    ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_custom_taxonomies_city', 0 ); 

add_filter('post_link', 'town_permalink', 10, 3);
add_filter('post_type_link', 'town_permalink', 10, 3);

function town_permalink($permalink, $post_id, $leavename) {
    if (strpos($permalink, '%city%') === FALSE) return $permalink;

// Get post
    $post = get_post($post_id);
    if (!$post) return $permalink;

// Get taxonomy terms
    $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'city');  
    if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms) && is_object($terms[0])) $taxonomy_slug = $terms[0]->slug;
    else $taxonomy_slug = 'not-city';

    return str_replace('%city%', $taxonomy_slug, $permalink);
}
```

**The result**:

- `http://example.com/city/moscow` - It works
- `http://example.com/category/shopping` - It works
- `http://example.com/category/shopping/supermarket/` - It works
- `http://example.com/moscow/shopping/` - It works
- `http://example.com/moscow/shopping/supermarket/` - It doesn’t!!!!!
- `http://example.com/moscow/shopping/supermarket/postname` – It doesn’t!!!!!

This post has a following link: `http: //mysite.ru/ moscow/shopping/postname`

But I need the links to contain the child-category.

1. I’ve tried to solve the task with another option: I’ve added the following code into function. php

```
function addRoutes() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%city%', '(.+?)');
    add_rewrite_rule('(.+?)/(.+?)/([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$', 'index.php?city=$matches[1]&category_name=$matches[2]&name=$matches[3]&page=$matches[4]', 'top');
  add_rewrite_rule('(.?.+?)(/[0-9]+)?/?$', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]', 'top');
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action('init', 'addRoutes');
```

**As a result**

`http://example.com/city/moscow` - Page not found 404 error.
`http://example.com/category/shopping` - Page not found 404 error..
`http://example.com/category/shopping/supermarket/` - Page not found 404 error..
`http://example.com/moscow/shopping/supermarket/postname`  –400 error

It seems the sustem doesn’t understand %city% 
What is wrong? 
Look forward for your help
Can anybody help me?
Thank you  very much!

---

I decided to change the structure of the URLs to:

- `example.com/city/moscow/category/shopping/` -Display all posts in this category in Moscow.
- `example.com/city/moscow/category/shopping/supermarket/` - Display all posts in this -child-category in Moscow.
- `example.com/city/moscow/category/shopping/supermarket/postname` - Display the post.

The code:

```
//The rewrite rules
function eg_add_query_vars( $query_vars ) {
    $new_vars = array( 'town' );

    return array_merge( $new_vars, $query_vars );
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'eg_add_query_vars' );

function eg_add_rewrite_rules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    $new_rules = array(
        'city/(.+?)/category/(.+?)/?$' => 'index.php?city=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '&category_name=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2),
'city/(.+?)/category/(.+?)/(.+?)/?$' => 'index.php?city=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '&category_name=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&category_name='. $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3),

//'city/(.+?)/category/(.+?)/(.+?)/(.+?)/?$' => 'index.php?city=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '&category_name=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&category_name='. $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3). '&page='. $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4),// This is me effort to write the rule for posts (doesn't work)   
        );
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'eg_add_rewrite_rules' );


//creating the permalink:
function city_permalink($permalink, $post_id, $leavename) {
    if (strpos($permalink, '%city%') === FALSE) return $permalink;

        // Get post
        $post = get_post($post_id);
        if (!$post) return $permalink;

        // Get taxonomy terms
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'town');  
        if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms) && is_object($terms[0])) $taxonomy_slug = $terms[0]->slug;
        else $taxonomy_slug = 'not-city';

    return str_replace('%town%', $taxonomy_slug, $permalink);}

    function wp_town_query( $query ) {
    if( isset( $query->query_vars['city'] ) ):
        if( $city = get_term_by( 'id', $query->query_vars['city'], 'city' ) )
            $query->query_vars['town'] = $city->slug;
    endif;
}
add_action( 'parse_query', 'wp_city_query' );
```

My settings in Permalink admin page:
city/%city%/category/%category%/%postname%/

as a result I have:
- `example.com/city/moscow/category/shopping/` -works
 - `example.com/city/moscow/category/shopping/supermarket/` - works
but still I can't understand how to write the rule for posts:
 - `example.com/city/moscow/category/shopping/supermarket/postname` - doesn't.
Pagination not working too.

I'll be glad to have any advice!

It's work:

```
'city/(.+?)/category/(.+?)/(.+?)/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?city=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '&category_name=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2). '&category_name=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3). '&name=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4), 
'city/(.+?)/category/(.+?)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?city=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '&category_name=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2). '&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3),
'city/(.+?)/category/(.+?)/?$' => 'index.php?city=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '&category_name=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2),
```

Comment: Please use the "edit" link and reformat your question. Hint: If you don't want to use your real domain, please use `example.com` that runs for exact that purpose. Thank you.

Comment: Strongly recommend using 'get_the_terms' instead of 'wp_get_object_terms' as 'get_the_terms' will cache the result. Using 'wp_get_object_terms' will result in that query running every time the 'post_link' filter runs, which is like 10 times on the Edit Post screen. Ref https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/category-template.php#L1238

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I will get negative points for this, but it should solve your problem, please dont be mad at me.
Before anyone downvote me for this, I must say that I have nothing to do with the developers of this plugin:

For custom taxonomies and custom post types I often use a plugin named "[Types](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/types/)". you can find it in install plugins at wordpress menu and should do the trick for you without any coding.